# Edit time format from to sources similar

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to edit the time format in "filetime" as in "now". Gets error on everything i try. How can i get "filetime" to be formatted like "now"?

```
from time import gmtime, strftime, localtime
import time
import os

now = strftime ("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", localtime())
print (now)

filetime = time.ctime(os.path.getctime (r"C:\Users\harila\file.txt"))
print (filetime)
```

Comment: What do you mean by >formatted like "now"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It will be easier to help you if the question is updated with an example of the desired output and the eventual Exception or error you got. See the help center in order to learn how to ask a great question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ctime = os.path.getctime(r"C:\Users\harila\file.txt")
filetime = strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(ctime))
```